# Using MAX function

Tags: sql, oracle

The below statement give me error
SQL Error: **ORA-00934** : group function is not allowed here
Does anyone know how to get around this error ?

```
update revisit set visitcounter=1234 where  visittimestamp=MAX(visittimestamp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
update revisit set visitcounter=1234 where  visittimestamp = (select MAX(visittimestamp) from revisit)
```